# Matplotlib.savefig ignoring axes and plotting black border around image

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, pyqt4, savefig

I have a matplotlib Figure embedded in a QtAggFigureCanvas (PyQt4) with titles and axis labels (example shown below). [image]

I implemented a button to save the figure to a png file. The figure was created with:

```
self.plkDpi = 100
self.plkFigure = Figure(dpi=self.plkDpi)
...
self.plkAxes = self.plkFig.add_subplot(111)
...
self.plkAxes.set_xlabel(...)
self.plkAxes.set_ylabel(...)
self.plkAxes.set_title(...)
```

When I hit my save button, the following code is executed:

```
self.plkFig.savefig('tmp.png', bbox_inches='tight', dpi=self.plkDpi)
```

For some reason, the axes and plot title are omitted from the final plot. But they are not cropped - there is a bounding black box around the figure that is just blank (see below)

[image]

No matter what I try, changing figsize, dpi, bounding box, etc. I cannot get the figure to save with the axis labels.

Comment: Could you create a [mcve] so that we can reproduce the problem?